# Visual Studio Tools for Git can't commit

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012

```
Opening repository: D:\testproject\DotNet.
Failed to push new glyph for D:\testproject\DotNet\DotNet.WinForms\DotNet.WinForm.User\DotNet.WinForm.User.csproj. Return code from SccGlyphChanged was -2147467263.
Failed to push new glyph for D:\testproject\DotNet\DotNet.WinForms\DotNet.WinForm.User\DotNet.WinForm.User.csproj. Return code from SccGlyphChanged was -2147467263.
Failed to push new glyph for D:\testproject\DotNet\DotNet.WinForms\DotNet.WinForm.User\DotNet.WinForm.User.csproj. Return code from SccGlyphChanged was -2147467263.
Undoing edit: D:\testproject\DotNet\DotNet.WinForms\DotNet.WinForm.Staff\DotNet.WinForm.Staff.csproj
Failed to push new glyph for D:\testproject\DotNet\DotNet.WinForms\DotNet.WinForm.User\DotNet.WinForm.User.csproj. Return code from SccGlyphChanged was -2147467263
```

when commit the solution,the output window show the error message.
who can give me a advice.

Comment: Are you using NTVS or PTVS? See: https://pytools.codeplex.com/workitem/2648

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**:

Fixed in Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 RC

**Initial post**

This has been [acknowledged as a bug](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9c32b6c0-ca56-4fff-849b-1375de8d5e04):

> No need to test it out as I mentioned in my last email. I have confirmed that this is a bug and that it has been fixed in an upcoming version.

There is no workaround at present - unless setting the source control provider to "None" and turning it on again when checking in.

There is [an open connect issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/972288). Please vote on it.